# iOS share custom dialog

Tags: ios, dialog, share

I was wondering which API is used to display this built-in dialog box?  I imagine, that once I know what the api is, I can figure out on my own how to do facebook, twitter, email etc..

Thanks..

[image: dialog box]

Comment: Yes it is duplicate - I just didn't know what to call it - the dialog I want is - UIActivityViewController

Answer (score 2):

Activity View Controller...

Try this framework

https://github.com/romaonthego/REActivityViewController

Comment: UIActivityViewController is the way to go..